# NHibernate Eager Load

Tags: nhibernate, hql, eager-loading

I've got an application that has the following HQL:

```
select distinct p from Position p
inner join fetch p.RequiredSkills rs
inner join fetch rs.Skill s
where s.Id in (:skills)
```

I've searched the positions where the position has the skill searched for.

Currently the hql works as far as returning positions with that skill, but it's only fetching the filtered skills.

I now want to return all of the skills associated to the position.

Is there any way for me to do this?

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a subquery:

```
select distinct p from Position p 
inner join fetch p.RequiredSkills rs 
inner join fetch rs.Skill s where p.Id in 
( select distinct pi.Id from Position pi
  inner join pi.RequiredSkills rsi
  inner join rsi.Skill si
  where si.Id in (:skills) )
```

Comment: wow... I can't believe I didn't think of that! - Thanks very much!